# jquery 3 step animation queue timing

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, queue, timing

I want to a have an animation where an element fades in (1000ms) while moving to the right (5000ms) and at the end it should fade out (at 4000ms, duration 1000ms) again while the element is still moving to the right.

I got the first two parts working but happen to need help with the timing setting of the last part(opacity: 0).

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var truck = $('.truck');
    truck.css("opacity", "0");
    truck.animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 1000
    }).animate({
        right: 15
    }, 5000).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000);

});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want it to take 5s or 4s to move?  You say both in your question.  Also, what's actually wrong, as that looks fine.

Comment: I want the whole animation to take 5s, the fade in should take 1s within the first second of the animation and the fade out should take 1s within the last second of the 5s animation. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: so the movement should take 5s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
var truck = $('.truck');
truck.css("opacity", "0");
truck
    .animate({
        right: 15
    }, {
        queue: false,
        duration: 5000
    })
    .animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000)
    .delay(3000)
    .animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000);
```

and here's a working jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/YTt9W/

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking for. I didn't know delay() until now.. :) Thank you!